# Get route Prefix in Twig or Controller

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to get prefix route in Controller or in Twig.

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog",name="root_post")
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}",name="post")
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
    }
}
```

I don't know if i can do

```
name="root_post"
```

Then I'd like to get this root like (in controller)

```
$this->get(request')->attributes->get('_route')
```

or (in Twig)

```
 app.request.attributes.get('_route')
```

I don't know if I can

Comment: @IgorPantović get "root_post"

Answer (score 2):

To check if your currently routed to the route you want, you can do the following in twig:

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') == 'root_post' %}
    <p>Routed to root_post!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thanks for comment, but i don't want the link, i'd like get the prefix route... for example in Twig i want know if I in "root_post" with $this->get(request')->attributes->get('_route')

Comment: thanks again but i can't do this if, because i use the same twig in different route